# How to fill a column given a condition that check a list on a index and assign given that index

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, assign

I will explain the complete context just in case, I found some solutions but only with an explicit `for i in range` or by setting a simple condition, not like the one I need.

I have a Dataframe with the columns: `post`, `author`, `DateTime`, `day_of_week`, `hours`

Now I want to calculate the probability of:
`that any author post a post on a specific day of the week` which is `number_post_that_week_day/total_post`

this is simple, can be done as follow ( probably not the best way but acceptable one):

```
count_by_field = data_set.groupby('day_of_week').count()['post']
total_by_field = data_set.groupby('day_of_week').count()['post'].sum()
temp_prob_by_field = count_by_field / total_by_field

# In case I need that the size of temp_prob_by_field should be 7
# but my sample, in some cases, only has Monday, Saturday
# With the next lines I will always have 7 records 
for index in range(size):
        if not index in temp_prob_by_field.index:
            temp_prob_by_field.loc[index] = 0
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I want to assign to the original `data_set` on a new column(`prob`), my probabilities values, but I want that it matches with the day of the week column, I mean:
If in a record, I have 3 ( which means Wednesday ) on column day_of_week. I want, that in that record on column `probs` the probability associated.

What I've been trying (without success):

```
data_set[data_set.loc[ data_set['hours'] in  temp_prob_by_field.index, temp_prob_by_field ]] 
= temp_prob_by_field.loc[data_set.loc[ data_set['hours'] in  temp_prob_by_field.index] # ‍♂️
```

I can do this by doing a for in as follow:

```
for i in range(7):
  data_set.loc[data_set['hours'] == i, 'probs' ] = temp_prob_by_field.loc[i]
```

I'm really new at pandas and seems to me this is not a good way to solve this problem, maybe I'm wrong.

As a [@not_speshai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal) as a data_sample to play with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1213)
c = ['post', 'author', 'datetime', 'day_of_week', 'hours']
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,0,3,5], size=(10,5)), columns=c)
data['post']='A post about something"


"""                  post  author  datetime  day_of_week  hours
0  A post about something       5         5            0      3
1  A post about something       1         1            1      5
2  A post about something       3         1            3      5
3  A post about something       5         3            5      1
4  A post about something       0         5            3      0
5  A post about something       3         3            0      1
6  A post about something       0         5            5      0
7  A post about something       3         3            5      3
8  A post about something       5         1            1      0
9  A post about something       1         0            0      3
"""
```

Comment: Please can you post a sample of `data_set` and the expected output?

Comment: @not_speshal I don't think in this case is need it but in any case, I just edit the post and a dd a sample to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `pd.merge`. Try:

```
data.merge(temp_prob_by_field, left_on="day_of_week", right_index=True)
```

Comment: @Me the scripter - Separately, your logic for calculating probabilities does not match what you describe in the question. If you're looking for `number_post_that_week_day/total_post` as you mention, you want to do: `temp_prob_by_field = data.groupby("day_of_week")["post"].sum()/data["post"].sum()`

Comment: I misunderstood you. You need to count, the number on a post is just for this example, to test, the numbers on the column post are just messages, not the number of posts. I will edit the description. I need to count how many posts are in the data_set and sum

Comment: If you're sure your computation is right, do it like this: `temp_prob_by_field = data_set.groupby('day_of_week')['post'].count()/data_set.groupby('day_of_week')['post'].count().sum()`. Also, this is exactly why I asked for sample data - it can clear up a lot of miscommunication :)